# Can you extend open layers layer class?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5, angular-openlayers

I am trying to extend OpenLayers class with es6 syntax in typescript.

I have run a few tests in jest to verify that my new class is a VectorLayer instance. I have been able to use methods like setSource and they appear to work in tests. However, when I add my class to the map it doesn't seem to work (there are no features on the map as expected). I removed the features from the context of the class and added them to a Vector Layer the normal way and the features work.

```js
  export class GridLayer extends VectorLayer {
  constructor () {
    super()

    const axisX = new LineString([[0, 1000], [1000, 1000]])
    const axisY = new LineString([[1000, 0], [1000, 1000]])
    const featureX = new Feature({ geometry: axisX })
    const featureY = new Feature({ geometry: axisY })

    this.setSource(new VectorSource({
      features: [
        featureX,
        featureY
      ],
    }))
  }
}
```

expected, should see some LineString on the map. actual, nothing on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in my import when importing the class to the file where the map was. Typescript didn't pick it up for some reason.

This is possible though. Very cool!